# List order - What UI is best

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, user-interface

I deal with a lot of lists of data in many scenarios CRM's, CMS's etc etc

However i now require the need to have a UI in the administration area in order to arrange the display order on the navigation menu for example on the front facing website.

I already have a column in my sql database [Order] as an int. I am building in asp.net and can't decide the best way to achieve my desired result / controls to use.

What are the best practices in achieving this or your recommendations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've used the ListView control for something very similar to this.  This would allow you to keep using your [Order] column and wouldn't require any changes to your database.

(By the way, my users are all 45++ years old and they all hate computers...but they're THRILLED with the simplicity of the ListView control.)

Answer (score 0):

The queue management on the Netflix web site is one of the best UI's for re-ordering lists that I've seen. I also like the way it handles deletion. Unfortunately, I don't think you can see it unless you have a Netflix account.

Here's a screenshot. You can edit the "List Order" text fields, but most people just drag and drop entire rows at a time, with target rows moving out of the way to make room. The "Top" button is also handy, since a new movie you might want to see soon will be added to the bottom of your queue. When you delete a row by clicking the X, a placeholder grey row stays behind with an undo button, until you leave the page.

[image]
<sub>(source: [thedigeratilife.com](http://www.thedigeratilife.com/images/netflix-queue-8.jpg))</sub>